# Hamiltonian MCMC information gathering

Tags: bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo, metropolis-hastings, hamiltonian-monte-carlo

I started gathering information about Hamiltonian MCMC and I would like to ask if someone knows some good papers or books.If it possible notes that give a detailed explanation of Hamiltonian MCMC.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you looked at the Stan website and the materials they link to? That world seem like an  obvious starting place.

Comment: I didn't know there is a Stan website.

Comment: http://mc-stan.org